# how to write array of values sum of digits it self a number in c# without using linq concept

Tags: c#

I have values like below

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] {25, 47, 60,98};// Not Exactly
```

so how to write

1. Sum of digits itself a number using array values of each number.

2.Total values Sum of digits itself a number

so please give me any idea
I know to write for single number like

```
int sumDigits (long n) 
{

    int sum = 0, int sum1 = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        sum1 += sum;
    }

    return sum1;
}
```

or

```
public int SumDigits(int value)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        int rem;
        value = Math.DivRem(value, 10, out rem);
        sum += rem;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your work is done. You just need to create a loop that iterates over your array, and calls your method for each element:

```
int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; ++i)
    arr2[i] = SumDigits(arr1[i]);
```

**Edit**: If you want to get the total, you can use:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; ++i)
    total += SumDigits(arr1[i]);
```

If you need both, you can obviously combine the two loops.